# Google sheets integration with golang

Tags: go, google-sheets

How to integrate with google sheets using golang, i have client_id and client_secret from google cloud console. I need to do it without json file

Comment: the problem i am facing is how to get OAuth2 token ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this official document to integrate Google Sheets using Golang. I hope this will be fully helpful for you.

[Google Sheets API Quickstart for Go](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go)

Comment: It uses json file to get creds, i need to use variables with client_id and client_secret

Comment: Follow my GitHub gist if you want to use variables with client_id and client_secret.

https://gist.github.com/Mubashir01234/92d06d578ad433566b089a3f0bee6afc